# can i use wildcard inside replace statement in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

MySQL experts. current data in table. COLUMN NAME IS URL
/abc1/pqr
/abc10/pqr

I need below result ie abc1 and abc10 should be replaced to xyz
/xyz/pqr
/xyz/pqr

How can I do this using replace command as I am unable to use wild card inside replace statement?

Currently I am using below 2 statements but I need a single statement.

```
UPDATE TABLE_URL
SET url = REPLACE(url, '/abc1/pqr', '/xyz/pqr')  

UPDATE TABLE_URL
SET url = REPLACE(url, '/abc10/pqr', '/xyz/pqr')
```

Comment: Please don't write in UPPERCASE.

Comment: The short answer is: **no**. Read about the [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function.

Comment: i dont want 2 separate Replace statments but a single statement. sorry for uppercase.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: no daniel. have checked this page before..didnt help..condition is different ...

Comment: any idea in this?

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
UPDATE TABLE_URL SET url = REPLACE(REPLACE(url, '/abc1/pqr', '/xyz/pqr'), '/abc10/pqr', '/xyz/pqr')
```

Work for you?

Comment: 1 to 10 numbers keep increasing..there is no max value set. so your query wont help. abc1,abc10..............abc111 etc.....

Comment: Then you are a bit stuck.

Comment: yes.. thats why need stackoverflow experts help. i was thinking of removing numbers substring and then replacing..but not sure how to do.